# making hover over text toggle with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to make some text I have as an attribute of an element toggle up when the cursor is hovering. Currently, I'm seeing weird things happening with this code, but feel like I'm very close...any ideas?

```
$(".hoverDes").mousemove(function(){
    $(".hoverDes").toggle(function(e){
        var hoverIt = $(this).attr("hoverDesDiv");
        $("#hoverDiv").text(hoverIt).show();
        $("#hoverDiv").css("top", e.clientY-30).css("left", e.clientX-50);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $("#hoverDiv").hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: Adding your HTML and/or a jsFiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough to me but from your code above I guess you need this

```
$(".hoverDes").hover(function(e){
    var hoverIt = $(this).attr("hoverDesDiv");
    $("#hoverDiv").text(hoverIt).show('slow');  
},
function(e){
    $("#hoverDiv").hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: This is what I had at first, which works and is fine, but I'd like a little bit sexier way to have it show up on the screen (hence the toggle).

Comment: Can you describe more specifically what do you exactly want ?

Comment: Well, currently when you hover, the text just pops up. Bam. But I'd like it to kind of toggle up more slowly (a bit of animation)..

Comment: There are other options like 'medium' and 'fast'

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
  hoverIt.show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
```

Comment: Basically I'm a freelance developer and currently no work to do so trying to kill time and helping others and also earning some reputation and through this learning something new each day.